# Make it less confusing for Low-rep users to flag as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, duplicate-questions, usability

When a low-rep user want to use an exact duplicate flag (click flag, "it doesn't belong here",  then it turns into a close-vote look-alike screen where "exact duplicate" lives) the verbiage is a bit strange.

[image: Trying to flag as duplicate is misleading]

"Exact duplicate" doesn't really stem from "doesn't belong here".

Comment: I vote for it being split out; Duplicates are very important, I'd rather have them able to see it rather than giving up or filing an Other flag instead (which they might not bother). It'd increase visibility

Comment: ... rather than flagging it the wrong way, e.g. one word: "Duplicate."

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn you're a mod, you should know the content of all 3,000,000 questions on SO. Just the word "duplicate" should be enough.

Comment: @BenBrocka: You're being sarcastic, aren't you? I can tell. Anyway, don't exaggerate it. There are only 2,948,747 questions on Stack Overflow, perfectly reasonable. 50,000 is a lot to round up by.

Comment: @minitechη Depends how many significant digits you're using. *scoff of obvious intellectual superiority*

Comment: There's some nice irony in me rounding down 51,253 to 50,000, too.

Comment: `"Exact duplicate" doesn't really stem from "doesn't belong here".` -- Indeed.  Some duplicates do belong and serve a useful purpose, especially as search targets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicates are important, but shuffling all this around would be quite painful from a coding standpoint.

To give better information scent, what I'd recommend for now is changing the text from

> It doesn't belong here

to

> It doesn't belong here, **or it is a duplicate**

Comment: just committed this, will take a few days to go live